# Is the combination of ADO.NET Entity Framework and ASP.MVC wrong by any chance?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have one solution with three projects.

1. DomainModel (C# Library with ADO.NET Entity Framework)
2. DomainModelTest (Unit Testing for Business Logic)
3. WebApp (Using DomainModel)

For some reason, I cannot even bring the view if I pass any of the objects in the DomainModel, not even simple.  I get the error below:

Any ideas?

> Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The
>   type
>   'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject'
>   is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference
>   to assembly 'System.Data.Entity,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 146:     Line 147:
>   [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute()]
>   Line 148:    public class
>   views_home_index_aspx :
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage,
>   System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState,
>   System.Web.IHttpHandler { Line 149:
>   Line 150:        private static bool
>   @__initialized;

I thought this might be helpful, the actual error comes up on the Default.aspx file in the line pointed below:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Change the current path so that the Routing handler can correctly interpret
        // the request, then restore the original path so that the OutputCache module
        // can correctly process the response (if caching is enabled).

        string originalPath = Request.Path;
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(Request.ApplicationPath, false);
        IHttpHandler httpHandler = new MvcHttpHandler();
        httpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current); //**HERE**
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(originalPath, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the reference to System.Data.Entity in your web project?

Comment: @Jason. Yes, I did. I removed it, re-added it, even check the version, also tried using statements in the homecontroller.  I even thought it was my views, so I delete them and re-create them. When they don't make reference to Objects created by the ado.net enti fram all is good, as soon as I try users or any other object, compile error happens. thanks.

Comment: Here I found the answer how to resolved the compilation issue
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129828/305197][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5129828/305197

Comment: In addition to adding the reference to the web.config file, you should also ensure that CopyLocal is set to True.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try adding the reference in your web.config, in the < assemblies > section.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I spent around 1.5 hour on this alone. Is this a known bug?  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't think I would call it a bug... Including the reference in the project is the first step.  If you want to use it in a controller you have to have a 'using' statement, if you want to use it in a view it needs to be in the web.config or imported declaritively in the view markup.  I banged my head against it too a few times, but I've learned my lesson now :)

Comment: @AJ, I'm pretty much of the opinion that this is a bug.  Normally when I add a reference to a web app, I only have to add it once.

Comment: i wouldn't say bug - i'd say poor error message for an undestandable bit of miscoding. "BUT IT IS F*ING REFERENCED!!"

Answer (score 16):

In web.config Add this

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add an empty ADO.NET Entity Data Model to your web-project, and then delete it. It will add the necessary references for you.