# Strange compilation error in Entity Framework and MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've just created a new MVC 2 application that references both an entity model library and a services library, and all compiles fine without running the app, but when I try running it, I get the following runtime error"

> Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I have double checked umteen times (e.g. Umpteen*n) and the cited assembly is refenced in all three projects.  If it wasn't, WTF would I not get a build error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is answered here:  [Is the combination of ADO.NET Entity Framework and ASP.MVC wrong by any chance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501616/is-the-combination-of-ado-net-entity-framework-and-asp-mvc-wrong-by-any-chance)

Answer (score 8):

For ASP.NET MVC 4 (.NET4.5)  change from

```
<system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 ...
```

To

```
 <system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" >
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Comment: Thanks this has been driving me mad for the last few days, finally solved.

Answer (score 7):

Just ran into this. Basically you need to add a reference to `System.Data.Entity` within your `web.config` (And make you have added the dll as a reference to the project too)

For `.NET3.5`

```
<assemblies>
 ..........
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
        PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
</assemblies>
```

For `.NET4` :

```
<assemblies>
 ..........
   <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
           PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</assemblies>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with Adding References of `System.Data.Entity` in your current project which is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my web project (targeting .net v4.5) had a dependency on another project containing EDMX models (targeting .net v4.0).

Once I upgraded the dependency project to target .net 4.5 and rebuilt this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Closing Visual Studio and reopening it again was enough to do the trick. As a note, I made recent changes to the edmx model.