# .Net assembly PublicKeyToken

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

Can often be seen a `PublicKeyToken` for an assembly, for example:

*C1.Win.C1Input.C1NumericEdit, C1.Win.C1Input.4, Version=4.0.20131.33296, Culture=neutral, **PublicKeyToken=7e7ff60f0c214f9a***

What is this part of the line mean?

Comment: It is the public key that's used in the [RSA algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsa_encryption).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PublicKeyToken` identifies the key that was used to sign a strong-named .net assembly. Read more about [Strong-Named Assemblies here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sx4kfb.aspx).

Comment: or Dgefri Rihter Clr via c#