# Debug Entity Framework 6 source code

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I would like to be able to step into Entity Frameworks source code and make some local edits to the source code for testing only.
I know I could enable the symbols and step into the code but I need to be able to make some edits to see if I can fix a bug in the code for SQL Geography.

When I download the source and include the projects in my solution, I received the "strong key" error.
So I removed the signed keys but now I am getting another error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   This leads me to believe that it can't find the DLL in my bin folder or that there is some assembly resolver that is not reading my bin first.

Is there any "easy" way to debug / edit Entity Framework source code locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the answer was very easy.
In the .config file I changed this

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

To this

```
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" requirePermission="false" />
```

Basically removing the PublicKeyToken fixed the issue.
[.Net assembly PublicKeyToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365349/net-assembly-publickeytoken)

Comment: This is not working for me. I did exactly what is said above and still the same exception.