# Could not load file or assembly '\bin\ABCpdf8-64.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, abcpdf

I have getting the following error message when I try to run the application.

Could not load file or assembly 'bin\ABCpdf8-64.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Please find below full details from FusionLog Viewer

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=unicode-1-1-utf-8"><!-- saved from url=(0015)assemblybinder: --><html><pre>
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (23/06/2015 @ 10:21:13) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131018. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\Code\xxxxx\Branches\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\bin\ABCpdf8-64.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Code/xxxxx/Branches/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Code\xxxxx\Branches\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e0fbcc81
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e0fbcc81
LOG: AppName = 6bf02849
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Code\xxxxx\Branches\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Code/xxxxx/Branches/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/bin/ABCpdf8-64.dll.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Code\xxxxx\Branches\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\bin\ABCpdf8-64.dll
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
ERR: Error extracting manifest import from file (hr = 0x80131018).
ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131018.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131018). Probing terminated.

</pre></html><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="charset=unicode-1-1-utf-8"><!-- saved from url=(0015)assemblybinder: --><html><pre>
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (23/06/2015 @ 10:21:13) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131018. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: Where-ref bind. Location = C:\Code\xxxxx\Branches\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\bin\ABCpdf8-64.dll
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Code/xxxxx/Branches/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Code\xxxxx\Branches\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e0fbcc81
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e0fbcc81
LOG: AppName = 6bf02849
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Code\xxxxx\Branches\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Code/xxxxx/Branches/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/bin/ABCpdf8-64.dll.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Code\xxxxx\Branches\xxxxx\xxxxx\xxxxx\bin\ABCpdf8-64.dll
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
ERR: Error extracting manifest import from file (hr = 0x80131018).
ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131018.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131018). Probing terminated.

</pre></html>
```

Comment: make sure you have `'\bin\ABCpdf8-64.dll'` in your bin folder.

Comment: I have abcpdf8-64.dll in the bin already.

Comment: ok, then check for assembly information in `web.config` and `packages.config`. see this- http://stackoverflow.com/a/10078384/1982631

Answer (score 1):

ABCpdf8-64.dll is *NOT* a .NET assembly. It is a native DLL, which will be called by ABCpdf.DLL, which *is* the .NET assembly.

This error message suggests to me that you tried to reference ABCpdf8-64.dll as a .NET assembly, perhaps from your web.config file. You should instead reference ABCpdf.dll.