# Force C# to load an assembly that is referenced only in a cshtml file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, razorengine

How to force C# run-time to load an assembly that is used only in a `.cshtml` file which is a Razor template?

I am using the JSON serialization functionality from `Newtonsoft`, the assembly is referenced by the project, but when the Razor engine compiles the template I get an error that the `Newtonsoft` namespace is not known. I also see that the dll is actually not loaded (I guess it makes sense since it is not referenced anywhere in the C# code). If I add a dummy line somewhere in my C# code that references any function from the assembly it is loaded and Razor is happy. Is there a way to specify that the assembly should be loaded even though it is not referenced? I really don't want to leave the dummy line in the code.

Comment: [How to add assembly in web.config file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456207/how-to-add-assembly-in-web-config-file-of-mvc-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, the compiler deletes the project reference during compilation/optimization, because it detects that it's not really being used by the code.

The **official** way to tell the runtime to load the assembly anyway by configuration, is to [add a reference in your `web.config` file inside the `<compilation>` section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10078384/97471)

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Newtonsoft.Json" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

That being said, sometimes the web.config is not available, or I want to avoid  bloating it with more and more lines, so I personally prefer the hack of making a one line reference in the code: (yes, a dirty bad nasty & silly hack, but I can't find much harm being done).

```
class LoadNewtonSoftHack
{
    private void DoNothing()
    {
        var o = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.Parse("{}");
    }
}
```

A third alternative would be to force the assembly load when the web app starts: (but ensure that your build copies the .dll in your `bin\` folder).

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Newtonsoft.Json.dll");
```

Comment: The `web.config` method would be preferable IMO.

Comment: Unless precompilation of views is turned on, the views aren't compiled until run-time anyway. Using the web.config in the way described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456207/how-to-add-assembly-in-web-config-file-of-mvc-4) is how you tell the run-time compilation to reference assemblies.

Comment: Your points are valid @spender, but I think this is a situation where more than one solution is applicable. I insist you add a new answer to this question.

Comment: I completely agree, but simply repeating the info that is in the other question/answer mostly leaves me wanting to press the dupe button ([which would be very final because of my gold badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/133351)). I think linking to this info in the comments is good enough... there's a reference to it in the comments to both the question and your answer.

Comment: To be fair, the answer would be a duplicate, but the question is not. I just added a 3rd option explaining how to add it into the web.config.

Comment: @spender: comments fade away. It's not enough to link in comments. If it's relevant it should go into the answer.

Comment: I started a conversation on meta about this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333983/regurgitating-answers-for-subtly-different-questions

Comment: Since I didn't even have a `web.config` file I chose the third approach and it worked fine, thanks:)