# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data'

Tags: c#, web-config

I receive this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data' or one of its dependencies
```

This is my code in Web.Config.

```
<add assembly="System.Data" />
```

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Data' could not be loaded.

```
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Could you help me out to figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried writing complete assembly name with token etc.?

Comment: Yes I tried and I get the same error, any idea? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021248/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-entity

Comment: You need to enable assembly load logging - see [fuslogvw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) for details. What you posted tells us it is turned _off_. No help at all.

Comment: Thanks Oded, unfortunatelly it is a shared hosting so probably I wont be able to turn on this feature.