# Could not load file or assembly... System.Data.Entity.dll

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.Entity.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

below my web.config file  - what could be the problem?? If I am logged in and using the application everything works. If I leave the app and not use it for for than 15 or 20 mins next time I try to enter the I get the error above

Thank you for any help in advanced

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="***" connectionString="Data Source=winserver;Initial Catalog=***;USER ID=***; Password=***; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->
    <add name="***" connectionString="Data Source=plcentral.ca;Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=False; User ID=***;Password=*** providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <!--<add name="***" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->
    <!--<add name="***" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|***.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <!--<add name="***" connectionString="Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=False; User ID=***;Password=***" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="GoogleAccount" value="email@email.com"/>
    <add key="GoogleAccountPwd" value="password"/>
    <!--<add key="GoogleAccount" value="email@email.com"/>
    <add key="GoogleAccountPwd" value="password"/>-->
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" >
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20000000"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
        <add namespace="MvcJqGrid"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Transactions" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Core" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thought would be good to add that If I test the app locally there is no error, just when on hosting server.

Answer (score 5):

In the solution explorer

Goto "Refrences" => Right click and "add refrences" => Go to ".Net" Tab and add "System.Data.Entity".

Rebuild the solution, hope this help.

Comment: I added the reference this way and rebuild was successful but unfortunately after 20-30 mins if inactivity I get the error again.

Comment: i am not sure about this but you can try this: "Clean the solution and add reference again and rebuild". Is there any "yellow mark" on the system.data.entity when there is error.

Comment: I have set up my visual studio with the SVN where the developers have uploaded the latest version. I did this so I could change some Views and CSS files but not too comfortable about changing anything else. Could you please provide me with a simple guide how to remove the system.data.entity and add again? Once removed it will remove the references from the web.config file on its own or I have to remove? Thank you,

Comment: ok I figured out how to clean the solution, I removed the system.data.entity.dll ---> added again --> rebuild with no errors --> uploaded to server and after 20-30 mins again same error =/

Answer (score 0):

How did you give reference / install Entity Framework for your project? Try to remove the reference and re-install using Nugget Package manager's install option. It configures the references for you automatically. If you do not have Nugget then you can add this extension from Visual Studio Tools > Extension menu. Entity framework dll is not present along with other .net dlls by default. 
Apart from this, I would suggest you to use EntityFramework version 5 instead of 4 you are trying to use. Many configuration issues has been fixed in v5. It also provide you code first approach which is fun to use :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">

  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129828/1310540