# Could not load file or assembly 'Entity.Data' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-assembly

This question is particular to Entity Framework 6.1.1 code first approach. I enabled migrations and went through the steps to create seed data. When I tried to initiate a read I got this error:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Products.ToList());
}
```

> *System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Entity.Data' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

I have tried replacing the assembly information within the web.config file in accordance with this thread: [Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021248/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-entity)

Nothing seems to be working. Also I should note that I have the Data Context and Migrations set up in a separate Data project.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you installed EF using Nuget or manual?

Comment: I am running VS2013 so I selected MVC 5 which I believe already had EF as a default. But then I uninstalled it and re-installed from Nuget to see if the default was the reason for this issue.